# How To Fix Missing Assembly Reference 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.dll' in Windows Store App Solution?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, catel

I have a Windows Store App solution which worked fine up until I installed Nuget Packages and Extentions from Catel. Now when I build the solution I get about 12 build errors with the following description originating from my startup project's .csproj file:

> *Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.dll'*

One would think, remove then add the reference again but you cannot manage the framework's assembly references.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Right click on your project => add reference => Windows 8.1 (tab) => select "Behaviors SDK (XAML)"

Comment: What do I do if I don't have the "Behaviors SDK (XAML)" option?  What do I need to install?

Comment: In 2015 try References -> "Add Reference" -> "Universal Windows" -> Extensions -> "Behaviors SDK (XAML)".

Comment: In 2016 (for UWP app) get it from nuget -> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/